# MySQL: Insert data in different table but have same id

Tags: mysql, database

I have some question : "insert data in different table but have same id (auto_increment)"
This is my twice table

student

> ----------------------
>  id  | name | class| 
>   ----------------------

score

> ---------------------------------------------
>  id | math | english | physical | year |
>   ---------------------------------------------

I have some data  like:
John , A , 90 ,80 ,70 ,2015
John , A , 70 ,90 ,50 ,2016

I want result Like:

student

> ----------------------
>  id  | name | class| 
>   ----------------------
>  1   | John  |  A  |
>   ----------------------

score

> ---------------------------------------------
>  id | math | english | physical | year |
>   ---------------------------------------------
>
> 1  | 90 | 80  | 70  |2015
>  1  | 70 | 90  | 50  |2016

Because table of student's   "id"  use  Auto_increment

If I want twice table have same id when I insert data

What SQL can I use ??
(I think `mysql_insert_id()` is Solution but not sure...)

Thank help !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I use mysql\_\* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: I see a lot of problems with your schema - what if a student can be in more than one class, or changes classes from one year to the next? What id more scores are needed to be saved? Your `score` table is denormalized and I see no need for that.

Comment: There's too much to cover here. See normalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are looking for the query to do so.First of all use PDO or mysqli for interacting with the database.Here I use PDO.

```
function my_select($query)
{
    global $dbserver,$dbuser,$dbpwd,$dbname;
    $dbh= new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbserver.';dbname='.$dbname.'',$dbuser,$dbpwd);
    $rs=$dbh->prepare($query); //prepared statements have numerous advantages over executing sql statements directly
    $rs->execute(); 
    return $db->lastInsertId(); //returns last inserted id of current db connection
}
```

And the query can be,

```
$l_id=my_select(query1)   // query to insert into student
$query2="INSERT INTO score (id,...) VALUES ('".$l_id."',...)" ;
my_select(query2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Auto Increament id in both tables than you need to add a column in `score` table for reference of `studentid`. For example:

```
Insert into student (name) values ('test');
```

Than use:

```
mysql_insert_id();
```

In last insert data into score table:

```
Insert into score (yourcolumns, studentid) values (yourcolumnvalue, last_inserted_id);
```

**Side note:** instead of `mysql_*` 
 functions use `mysqli_*` or PDO becuase `mysql_*` is deprecated and not available in PHP 7.